# embed flash object transparency issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

I want the following flash  object to load without the grey background since it looks bad when the page is loading :s

```
           <object data="http://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/track=261125661/size=tall2/bgcol=FFFFFF/linkcol=4285BB//" type="text/html" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="150" height="450">
    <param name="movie" value="http://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/track=261125661/size=tall2/bgcol=FFFFFF/linkcol=4285BB//"><param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="allowNetworking" value="always">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never">
<object data="http://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/track=261125661/size=tall2/bgcol=FFFFFF/linkcol=4285BB//" type="text/html" width="150" height="450"></object></object>
```

I tried removing the bgcolor value, i have set transparency in wmode...anyone got a suggestion?
 thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="150" height="450">
    <param name="movie" value="http://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/track=261125661/size=tall2/bgcol=FFFFFF/linkcol=4285BB//">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="allowNetworking" value="always">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never">
    <embed src="http://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/track=261125661/size=tall2/bgcol=FFFFFF/linkcol=4285BB//" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="150" height="450" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Also consider using swfobject, it is the preferred method of embedding flash on the web.

Comment: This only works if your background is white.  This isn't a true fix.